# Creating and Assign variable value on template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my view I have a table that will be filled dinamycally with data from server. This table should have at least 5 rows, which means that if my server doesn't return 5 sets of data, the table should be filled with `5 - (n_sets_returned)`. To make that happen I guess the easy way would be to define a variable and set it to the number of sets returned, but I can't make it. I tried as follow:

```
<tbody class="center-alignment xcompact" ng-init="cont = 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.val1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.val2}}</td>
        <td>{{row.val3}}</td>
        <td>{{row.val5}}</td>
        {{cont = $index}}
    </tr>                       
    <tr ng-repeat="n in [] | range:(5-cont)">
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is I don't even know if this would work (probably not) because the empty rows appears before the filled ones, what means Angular obviously doesn't wait for server response to fill the empty rows.

I'm pretty new at Angular. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not put this logic in the controller? `while(arr.length < 5) { arr.push({}); }`

Comment: The controllers are all created by a single function, so they are pretty much the same except the URL of the server I will get data from. Therefore it would be hard to "personalize" a single controller. But then again, I'm new at this, do you think it would be better to separate all controllers? Thanks.